# Propeller Torque

Tags: propeller, engine, aircraft-physics

We know that every rotating device generates torque . How does a single engine propeller A/C (Piper) counter-balance the torque which is being produced by nose propeller?

Answer (score 1):

Using the ailerons on the wings.

The torque is a roll moment and the ailerons will be able to counteract that easily.